# MATLAB 3D plotting of beam modal curvature

Tags: matlab, 3d

I am trying to plot the modal curvature of a beam in xy plane. I have divided the beam in elements in x and y plane. i have coordinates of the element center and using that I have calculated the vertex coordinates. I have plotted the mode shape using those vertices coordinate using fill command. Then I calculated the modal curvature in x and y direction and combined them. Now i want to plot it using matlab 3D plot but not sure how to do it so that elements are placed as per x and y coordinates. Please help. I have attached the code below

```
`close all;clear all;clc
% Read cent.txt and eigenvector_0    1.txt
cent = load('cent.txt');
eigen = load('eigenvector_0    1.txt');
dsize = sqrt((cent(1,1)-cent(2,1))^2+(cent(1,2)-cent(2,2))^2); % user can change;
sc=1;
% Find number of elements
num_elem = size(cent, 1);
% num_modes = size(eigen, 2);
bc=[1 101 201 301 401 501 601 701 801 901 1001 1101 1201 1301 1401 1501 1601 1701 1801 1901];

eigvec_full=zeros(1,num_elem*3);
%Get the full eigen;
ibc=1;j=1;
for i=1:num_elem
    if (bc(ibc)~=i)
        eigvec_full(3*i-2)=eigen(j);eigvec_full(3*i-1)=eigen(j+1);eigvec_full(3*i)=eigen(j+2);
        j=j+3;
    else
        if (ibc<length(bc))
            ibc=ibc+1;
        end
    end
end

% Initialize output matrices
MC = zeros(num_elem, 4);
MM = zeros(num_elem, 3);
Z = zeros(num_elem, 4);

%Make CO of the beam
figure(1)
for i=1:num_elem
    vertX(i,1)=cent(i,1)-dsize/2;vertX(i,2)=cent(i,1)+dsize/2;vertX(i,3)=cent(i,1)+dsize/2;vertX(i,4)=cent(i,1)-dsize/2;
    vertY(i,1)=cent(i,2)-dsize/2;vertY(i,2)=cent(i,2)-    dsize/2;vertY(i,3)=cent(i,2)+dsize/2;vertY(i,4)=cent(i,2)+dsize/2;
    x=[vertX(i,1) vertX(i,2) vertX(i,3) vertX(i,4)];
    y=[vertY(i,1) vertY(i,2) vertY(i,3) vertY(i,4)];
    xx(i)=mean(x);      
    yy(i)=mean(y);    
    MM=[i,x,y];
    fill(x,y,'c');hold on; axis equal
    u1 = eigvec_full(3*i-2);v1 = eigvec_full(3*i-1);r1 = eigvec_full(3*i);
    dx1 = vertX(i,1)-cent(i,1);dy1 = vertY(i,1)-cent(i,2);
    dx2 = vertX(i,2)-cent(i,1);dy2 = vertY(i,2)-cent(i,2);
    dx3 = vertX(i,3)-cent(i,1);dy3 = vertY(i,3)-cent(i,2);
    dx4 = vertX(i,4)-cent(i,1);dy4 = vertY(i,4)-cent(i,2);
    d1 = sqrt(dx1*dx1+dy1*dy1);sr12 = sin(r1);cr12 = cos(r1);
    cthet1 = dx1/d1;sthet1 = dy1/d1;
    cthet2 = dx2/d1;sthet2 = dy2/d1;
    cthet3 = dx3/d1;sthet3 = dy3/d1;
    cthet4 = dx4/d1;sthet4 = dy4/d1;
    DvertX(i,1)=vertX(i,1)+(u1*sc+d1*(cthet1*cr12-sthet1*sr12-cthet1));
    DvertY(i,1)=vertY(i,1)+(v1*sc+d1*(sthet1*cr12+cthet1*sr12-sthet1));
    DvertX(i,2)=vertX(i,2)+(u1*sc+d1*(cthet2*cr12-sthet2*sr12-cthet2));
    DvertY(i,2)=vertY(i,2)+(v1*sc+d1*(sthet2*cr12+cthet2*sr12-sthet2));
    DvertX(i,3)=vertX(i,3)+(u1*sc+d1*(cthet3*cr12-sthet3*sr12-cthet3));
    DvertY(i,3)=vertY(i,3)+(v1*sc+d1*(sthet3*cr12+cthet3*sr12-sthet3));
    DvertX(i,4)=vertX(i,4)+(u1*sc+d1*(cthet4*cr12-sthet4*sr12-cthet4));
    DvertY(i,4)=vertY(i,4)+(v1*sc+d1*(sthet4*cr12+cthet4*sr12-sthet4));
    x1=[DvertX(i,1) DvertX(i,2) DvertX(i,3) DvertX(i,4)];
    y1=[DvertY(i,1) DvertY(i,2) DvertY(i,3) DvertY(i,4)];
    fill(x1,y1,'y');hold on; axis equal
end

[X, Y] = meshgrid(xx,yy);


figure(2)
for i=1:num_elem
    if i==1
        uxx(i,:)=(DvertX(i+1,:)-2*DvertX(i,:))/(dsize*dsize);
        uyy(i,:)=(DvertY(i+1,:)-2*DvertY(i,:))/(dsize*dsize);
    elseif i==num_elem
        uxx(i,:)=(-2*DvertX(i,:)+DvertX(i-1,:))/(dsize*dsize);
        uyy(i,:)=(-2*DvertY(i,:)+DvertY(i-1,:))/(dsize*dsize);
    else
        uxx(i,:)=(DvertX(i+1,:)-2*DvertX(i,:)+DvertX(i-1,:))/(dsize*dsize);
        uyy(i,:)=(DvertY(i+1,:)-2*DvertY(i,:)+DvertY(i-1,:))/(dsize*dsize);
    
    U = sqrt(uxx(i, :).^2 + uyy(i, :).^2);    

    Z(i,:)=mean(U);
    surf(X,Y,Z);
    hold on;
end
colorbar; 
xlabel('X Coordinate');
ylabel('Y Coordinate');
end`
```

I an expecting a 3d graph showing the elements position in xy plane. The length of my beam in x direction

```
type here
```

is 1.5 meter and width is .3m